# Why is it inappropriate to describe a set in this way?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm perfectly aware of one way of describing the set of squared natural natural numbers as such: $\{x|x=n^2,n\in N\}$ but what is wrong with the more compact $\{n^2|n\in N\}$?  A similar notion could be used to make any number of sets written in a more compact form.  I guess my question is: "Is it ever APPROPRIATE to start a set description of this type with anything other than a generic variable representing a member of the set?"  If not, then why not condense the notation down to just something like $\{x=n^2, n\in N\}$?  Excuse my blissful ignorance.  Even though I have a degree in math, my study of set theory and and underlying foundations was extraordinarily weak at best.

Comment: $\{n^2\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is perfectly standard notation.

Comment: I see no problem at all with your shortened notation.

Comment: I suppose you meant $\{x|x=n^2,n\in N\}$ in the first description, not $\{x|x=n^2,x\in N\}$... Anyway, the second one (i.e. $\{n^2|n\in N\}$) is perfectly normal.

Comment: I think your second version is not only appropriate, but it is superior to the first. Why do you think the second is inappropriate?

Comment: What makes you think your more lengthy notation is "more appropriate"?

Comment: In the older texts, it is common to require that set  builder notation  be used. As others have said, there is a perfectly valid justification to do it your way too.

Answer (score 4):

$\{n^2\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is perfectly appropriate. It has the form $\{F(x)\mid x\in A\}$ which corresponds directly to the *Axiom of Replacement* in axiomatic set theory.

It is *also* okay to write $\{x \mid x=n^2, n\in\mathbb N\}$. That should probably be taken as shorthand for
$$ \{x\in \mathbb N\mid \exists n\in\mathbb N: x=n^2 \} $$
which matches the schema of the *Axiom of Separation*, namely $\{x\in A\mid \phi(x)\}$. But it is still (for no good reason) more complex and less clear than $\{n^2\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, so it generally wouldn't be written in that way.

Comment: If anything, I wouldn't use the $\{x\mid x=n^2,\dots\}$ notation, the lack of the existential quantifier makes it unnecessarily unclear.